# Multiple slides in one page - w3schools sample

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I edited the w3schools example to put multiple sliders on a web page. The example shows two slides. I added a third. Now, the arrow on the right side shows all three images on all three sliders, but the arrow on the left side only shows two images.

w3schools Multi Sliders:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_multiple

This is the original code plus the addition of a third slider.

```
html><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
.mySlides1, .mySlides2, .mySlides3 {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 720px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a grey background color */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2 style="text-align:center">Multiple Slideshows</h2>

<p>Slideshow 1:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides1" style="display: none;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1" style="display: none;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1" style="display: block;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-0, 0)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">❯</a>
</div>

<p>Slideshow 2:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides2" style="display: none;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_band_chicago.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2" style="display: none;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_band_la.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2" style="display: block;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_band_ny.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">❯</a>
</div>

<p>Slideshow 3:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides3" style="display: none;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides3" style="display: none;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides3" style="display: block;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 2)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">❯</a>
</div>

<script>
let slideIndex = [1,1];
let slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);
showSlides(1, 2);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  let i;
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
  if (n < 2) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
}
</script> 
</body></html>
```

So, I need the left arrow to show the 3 images, not 2 only.

Comment: Your HTML syntax is not correct. please fix it.

Comment: Do you mean to put the full code here or are you saying there are errors in the code? The code is that of w3schools. I only modified a couple of values in the javascript code.

Comment: Then you didn't copy the code properly. You miss a <div> in the beginning.